# Body field doesn't display in any view mode

Tags: 7, entities

I inserted some articles in my Drupal 7 site, the body field  doesn't display, the manage display setting is ok, I tried to change the theme.
Even though I still to display it in edit mode.
One thing is that I imported this content type with bundle copy , it's the same Article default content type with some custom fields.
[image]

Comment: Are you using the Panels module?

Comment: no, I'm not using it

Comment: what is text format of the body ? full_html ,formatted_html or  plain text ...?

Comment: @zhilevan filtred_html

Comment: @learner123  try to `var_dump($node->body);` (or if you install devel module  `dpm($node->body);`  and write result in question for additional details.

Comment: @zhilevan plz see the screeshot above

Comment: @learner123 it seem's ok , are you  sure you didn't select summary in display manager? plese sure that you not select summary (becasue summary is empty).  also try  `dpm($content);` . I think prlbelm is only in displaying

Comment: @zhilevan no, I didn't http://s32.postimg.org/6lpifxk5h/Selection_003.png

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the body field and I recreate it again. that's slove my problem, while I have not yet had any contents
I didn't find a second solution